# Making object instances observable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

### Background

Consider the following:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

function MyClass() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MyClass, EventEmitter);

MyClass.prototype = {
  method1: function() {
    this.emit('method1');
  }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

The goal here is to `require` this module and create instances that are all 'observable' in that their events can pass data to other objects that will handle these events.

I use this module like so:

```
var MyClass = require('./my-module-index');
var instance = new MyClass();
instance.method1();
```

Here's the catch:

Calling `method1` throws the error:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

whose stack trace points to the `emit` call.

### Question

Should this be a singleton class to have the Observable behavior as implemented or is there something subtle to get instances to emit events that can be handled elsewhere?

I would normally think this was a scoping issue but since the method is on the Object's prototype, `this` should be referring to any instance (provided `new` is used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're completely blowing away the prototype for `MyClass` by assigning it to a brand new object so no wonder `emit` is `undefined`. Try this instead:

```
MyClass.prototype.method1 = function() {
  this.emit('method1');
};
```

That should work.

[Here is a good write up on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) about the prototype chain and how method lookup / inheritance works in JavaScript.

Comment: That's what I was thinking! I'm trying it out right now.